# Replace beginning of Request URI with a filter

Tags: google-analytics

I have a series of pages on my site that pass the values "/es/es" in the domain.

I would like to replace these with a cleaner "/es" i.e. "/es/page-name"

I have tried to do this using a search and replace filter in Google Analytics as follows:

Search String on Request URI = ^/es/es$

Replace String = /es

Could anyone identify where I am going wrong, whether this is the correct method or even possible?

Comment: are they ALL just "/es/es"? Or are they "/es/es/page-name"?

Comment: you have "^/es/es$" which is essentially matching ONLY "/es/es" since you have ^ start with and $ end. So it won't match if there's anything else in the URI.

Comment: Hi @XTHOTHEL, yes you are correct there are pages where it is as the start of the URI. I have changed the string to "^\/es\/es\/.*" and the replace string "\/es\/" .It giving the same result of returning "/es/es"

Comment: The filter applies only to data that's coming in from that point in time forward, it doesn't affect data that's already in GA.

Comment: @XTHOTHEL - yes, I understand. I am checking in real time reports, I have been testing today on another filter that changes the Request URI and can see the changes live

Comment: Can you try... "/es/es" and "/es" as the search and replace values? Also use the "Filter Verification" section to confirm instead of looking at the real-time.

Comment: That seems to have worked (removing the regex special characters. Thank you @XTOTHEL